# 2 clicks to print page from code-behind asp.net

Tags: asp.net, web-applications

I am using Asp.Net and have a printer friendly button on the web page. I have a printer friendly css file for printing which is fired from code behind. This works but it has to be clicked twice initially, then only once after that. Anyone know why?

```
   Protected Sub PrintPartialButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PrintPartialButton.Click
    With PrintPage
        .Attributes.Remove("media")
        .Attributes.Remove("href")
        .Attributes.Add("media", "print")
        .Attributes.Add("href", "printer_friendly.css")
    End With

    PrintPartialButton.Attributes.Add("onclick", "window.print(); return false;")
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not just include the printer_friendly.css in the full page load?  The way you have it now users can't use their normal print button to get the right style sheet.

Comment: Well I suppose i can reset it to the initial page css after printing the partail page. I'll edit the code. This way they can print the whole page with the normal print button.

Comment: Usually having an "in page" print button operate differently from the browsers print button is a bad idea.  However, sending 2 style sheets to the browser one for display and the other for printing is common.

Comment: But why does it take 2 clicks?

Comment: @Chris So maybe pushing the partial page i want to print should be displayed in new window?

Comment: Because at the first click. The button doesn't have an onclick event. You are adding it after first click.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to click it twice initially because you are attaching the "onclick" event on your first click.  You need to attach it on page_load or page_init.  Seems like you would be better off not using a server control for this or just add "OnClientClick='window.print();return false;'" to the server control's markup.